# Is there a way to see the information contained within [object][object] using firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, firebug

I'm using console.log(variable) and firebug to examine javascript code. Occasionally, I get [object][object] as the value. 
Is there anyway of getting more information than just [object][object]?

**EDIT:** [object Object] is not clickable

**EDIT2:** I was able to log the information using `console.log("My EPIC Object", epicObject);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on it and you will see what it contains (as long it is not a string).

[image: click it]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/YEaW3/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Neal. Unfortunately, [object][object] isn't clickable for me. I've been able to examine other objects by clicking them, but not [object][object]

Comment: @moomoochoo are you sure you are not logging a string? Please make a fiddle with your code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: It's possible that it is a string, but I don't really know. I'm examining the script to try and understand it. Is an object only unclickable in firebug when it is a string or are there other possibilities?

Comment: @moomoochoo It sounds like you are coercing the Object into a String, typically achieved through concatenation, eg: `console.log("My EPIC Object: " + epicObject)`.  This is better logged via `console.log("My EPIC Object", epicObject);`.

Comment: @JonnyReeves That worked for me. Thank you so much! Could you put your reply as an answer?

Comment: @moomoochoo oy, that **is** my answer. you were displaying it as a string, therefore it did not display...

Comment: @Neal I appreciate your answer, but I wanted to know how to SEE the information contained within [object][object] which is what JohnnyReeves gave. As it is, your answer doesn't solve my problem. I'm sorry if I sounded rude.

Comment: @Neal if you edit your answer to include the console.log info I will mark it up (or choose it as the answer if Johnny doesn't post an answer (because I said I would accept his)).

Comment: @moomoochoo I said in my answer that it would work if it was **not** a string, and you were logginf a string, thereofre it did **not** work.

Comment: Hey what the hell? What about my points, my precious points?!

Answer (score -1):

You could try logging it with console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)).